# flask-security ImportError: cannot import name 'db'

Tags: flask, flask-security

I know this is probably a circular import error but I cannot figure out a solution. The application, so far, is very vanilla. It is the flask-security tutorial with a models.py added. This is in preparation to add blueprints to the project.

from app import db
ImportError: cannot import name 'db'

```
config.py
run.py
---app
------__init__py
------models.py
```

run.py

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**init**.py

```
from config import Config
import app.models

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, \
    login_required

db = SQLAlchemy()

# Create app
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    db.init_app(app)

    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, models.Users,
                                             models.usersRoleNames)
    security = Security(app, user_datastore)

    return app

# Views
@app.route('/')
@login_required
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

models.py

```
from app import db
from flask_security import UserMixin, RoleMixin

users_roles = db.Table('users_roles',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
        db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users_role_names.id')))


class usersRoleNames(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))


class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255))
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    last_login_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    current_login_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    last_login_ip = db.Column(db.String(100))
    current_login_ip = db.Column(db.String(100))
    login_count = db.Column(db.Integer)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('usersRoleNames', secondary=users_roles,
                            backref=db.backref('users',
                                               lazy='dynamic'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring your `db` object in `models.py` and import it in `app/__init_.py`

**models.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy                                         

db = SQLAlchemy()
...
```

**app/__init__.py**

```
def create_app():                                                               
    app = Flask(__name__)                                                       
    app.config.from_object(Config)                                              
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True                                                  

    from app.models import db, Users, usersRoleNames                            
    db.init_app(app)                                                                                                             

    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, Users,                         
                                             usersRoleNames)                    
    security = Security(app, user_datastore)                                    

    return app
```

Comment: it fixed one problem and created another. thanks for the advice. let me get this part worked out and I will mark it resolved. users_roles = db.Table('users_roles',
AttributeError: type object 'SQLAlchemy' has no attribute 'Table'.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simple solution to the circular import problem with *flask-security*. This solution is particularly useful when the models are declared across different files.

---

#### 1. Create a folder named `models`:

All our models will live inside this folder.

Sample folder structure could look like this

```
models/
├── _db.py
├── __init__.py
├── tickets.py
└── users.py

0 directories, 4 files
```

#### 2. Create a file named `_db.py`:

Declare the `db` object in this file.

The file name could be anything but starting the file name with an *underscore* ensures that the `db` object is always imported first when the import statements are sorted.

*('VS Code provided an option to automatically sort the imports, so using that doesn't cause any issues.')*

**`_db.py`**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

#### 3. Import `db` object from `_db.py` file:

Now we can import the `db` object from the `_db.py` file created above:

**`users.py`**

```
from ._db import db
from flask_security import RoleMixin, UserMixin

users_roles = db.Table(
    # Table definition
)

class usersRoleNames(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    # Table definition
    ...

class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
    # Table definition
    ...
```

#### 4. Import everything in `__init__.py` file (*optional*):

Create a **init**.py file and import all the models and the `db` object inside it.

`__init__.py`

```
from ._db import db
from .tickets import Tickets
from .users import Users, users_roles, usersRoleNames

'''
Below part is optional 
but I like to do it anyways
'''

__all__ = [
    'db',
    'Tickets',
    'Users',
    'users_roles',
    'usersRoleNames',
]
```

By importing everything inside the `__init__.py` file we can import from models folder directly.

So we can do

```
from .models import db, Tickets, Users
```

Instead of this

```
from .models._db import _db
from .models.tickets import Tickets
from .models.users import Users
```

**Just a thought:** I am not sure if it's a bad practice to start a python file name with an *'underscore'*. If you have an opinion please share your thoughts.

Comment: Thank you for responding and posting this. I am no longer using flask-security so I don't have the ability to test this. This project has migrated to Vue.js(Nuxt) as a stand alone client/front end with a flask stand alone/back end. However, the site security has been completely re-written. I would imagine this will be helpful for others though.

Comment: Glad I could help.